Tightness of Slepian's inequality
Suppose $X,Y$ are jointly Gaussian with zero mean, unit variance, and covariance $\rho \geq 0$. Slepian's inequality implies that
$$
\Pr[X \leq \mu \text{ and } Y \leq \nu] \geq \Pr[X \leq \mu] \cdot \Pr[Y \leq \nu].
$$
How tight is this inequality?
When $\mu = \nu$, I can prove that
$$
\Pr[X,Y \leq \mu] \leq \Pr[X \leq \mu]^2 + \rho \Pr[X\leq \mu] \Pr[X > \mu].
$$
This is tight when $\rho = 0$ and when $\rho = 1$.

Is this known? Is there a similar inequality when $\mu \neq \nu$?


"Tight" has several reasonable interpretations here, depending on how you implicitly quantify all the parameters in the inequality: namely, $\mu,$ $\nu,$ and $\rho.$  For any $\rho,$ there exist $\mu$ and $\nu$ for which the two sides of the inequality can be made arbitrarily close according to various metrics, too.  (After all, in the limit as $\mu$ and $\nu$ grow large, both sides approach either $0$ or $1.$) Could you therefore be more specific about your question?

My conjecture is an upper bound of the form $\Pr[X \leq \mu, Y \leq \nu] \leq \Pr[X \leq \mu] \Pr[Y \leq \nu] + \rho \sqrt{\Pr[X \leq \mu] \Pr[X > \mu] \Pr[Y \leq \nu] \Pr[Y > \nu]}$. An even better bound would be a linear interpolation between $\Pr[X \leq \mu] \Pr[Y \leq \nu]$ and $\Pr[X \leq \min(\mu,\nu)]$.
